# PhoneGap + Xcode + UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad

Tags: xcode, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap + Xcode to create an app. Is there any way I can show the UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad when using this tag in the HTML:

`<input type="" />`

Any work-arounds, mods, tweaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the input type="number" and then pattern="[0-9]*" to bring up a number pad.

Comment: this does not show the "." on the keyboard for decimal numbers

Answer (score 1):

[See the documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

I guess you can use

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"></input>
```

or

```
<input type="tel"></input>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: this does not show the "." on the keyboard for decimal numbers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204762/showing-an-input-that-only-allows-numbers-and-the-decimal-point