# Showing an input that only allows numbers and the decimal point?

Tags: iphone, html, input, cordova

Is there any way to define an `<input>` that shows a keyboard input that only allows numbers and the decimal point (or comma for international users)?

`<input type='tel'>` shows phone crap I don't need, and no decimal point
`<input type='number' pattern='[0-9]*'>` shows all numbers, but no decimal point

What can I do to get the input I need?

Comment: -1? I misunderstood your question at first I suppose. What I gave is correct HTML5 that causes the proper data validation in fully compliant browsers. The [Apple Developer's Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#codinghowtos/Mobile/UserExperience/_index.html) listing 15 gives the patterns that will actually cause different iphone keyboards to be displayed. I imagine the list is exhaustive, and good day sir.

Comment: @IamChuckB: Wrong answers get downvoted. It isn't personal. Oddly enough, I would have accepted your comment as correct with an upvote!

Comment: Fair enough. No harm, no foul I hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were doing this in a bona fide iOS app, you could probably add buttons of your own on top of the keyboard, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824325/iphone-adding-a-button-to-keyboard-existing-accessory-view-keyboard-from-uiwe), which is about the accessory view but the same process would work.

Otherwise, IamChuckB is right and the [five keyboard types given in the Apple Developer's Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#codinghowtos/Mobile/UserExperience/_index.html) are exhaustive.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this attribute to your type="number" field:

```
pattern="\d+(\.\d*)?"
```

this will allow only digits with/without a decimal point and the floating numbers on the right.

Comment: NOTE #1: this will still bring the full keyboard but in the number/symbol pane be default. The user can still switch to alphanumeric **BUT upon onblur event, the pattern kicks in and removes any alphanumeric characters (but not numbers).**
NOTE #2: It has to be both type="number" and pattern="\d+(\.\d*)?" in order to work!. Plus the browser needs to support html5. This works in normal browsers and Safari in IOS.

Comment: The latest versions of Chrome seem to error if you combine type="number" with this (and any) pattern. Chrome only reliably applies patterns to input type="text".

Comment: I tried the above but it does not work, and I find confusing for the user showing the full keyboard when only numbers and a dot are allowed. I ended up using 2 inputs type="number" separated by a static "."

Answer (score 1):

Please see my project of the cross-browser filter of value of the text input element on your web page using JavaScript language: [Input Key Filter](https://github.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter) . You can filter the value as an integer number, a float number, or write a custom filter, such as a phone number filter. See an example of code of input a float number

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Input Key Filter Test</title>
 <meta name="author" content="Andrej Hristoliubov anhr@mail.ru">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 
 <!-- For compatibility of IE browser with audio element in the beep() function.
 https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible -->
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/InputKeyFilter.css" type="text/css">  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/Common.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/anhr/InputKeyFilter/master/InputKeyFilter.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Float field</h1>
Float field: 
<input id="Float"
 onchange="javascript: onChangeFloat(this)"
 onblur="inputKeyFilter.isNaN(parseFloat(this.value), this);"
/>
<script>
 CreateFloatFilter("Float");
 
 function onChangeFloat(input){
  inputKeyFilter.RemoveMyTooltip();
  var elementNewFloat = document.getElementById("NewFloat");
  var float = inputKeyFilter.parseFloat(input.value);
  if(inputKeyFilter.isNaN(float, input)){
   elementNewFloat.innerHTML = "";
   return;
  }
  elementNewFloat.innerHTML = float + " or localized value: " + float.toLocaleString();
 }
</script>
 New float: <span id="NewFloat"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Also see my page ["Float field:" of the example of the input key filter](https://anhr.github.io/InputKeyFilter/)

Comment: Please make sure to include self-attribution whenever linking to one of your projects elsewhere on the web; otherwise, it's considered spam.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is "self-attribution". What I need to do?

Comment: Put a note of some sort near your links to clarify that you wrote them or whatever.

Comment: For example to replace from 'Also see "Float field:" of the example of the input key filter' to 'Also see my page "Float field:" of the example of the input key filter'. Is correct?

Comment: Ready. Any way I find it is very strange

Answer (score 0):

=> It will allow only single decimal dot (.)

=> It will only allow three digit decimal values after dot. you can modified by changing to {1,3} into below RegEx.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {

        if (!string.length)
            return YES;

        NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]+)?(\\.([0-9]{1,3})?)?$";
        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression
                                                                               options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                                 error:nil];
        NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString
                                                            options:0
                                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];
        if (numberOfMatches == 0)
            return NO;


        return YES;

    }
```