# Input type for iOS numpad keyboard with comma

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I know this is an old question.. but I can't find any valid answer.

I need to trigger the numpad on iOS device with comma, the keyboard type is                    `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad`, you can see it here:

[image]

I need to trigger it **with an HTML input element**, is it possible?

For reference, here are some older questions without a solution:

[question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896114/phonegap-xcode-uikeyboardtypedecimalpad)

[question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204762/showing-an-input-that-only-allows-numbers-and-the-decimal-point)

[question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002146/show-decimal-keyboard-in-html5-ios-7-ios-8)

EDIT: It seems that nobody has understood, the problem is to show this keyboard **with an HTML input field**, not with native code (also, **the problem is not about comma or dot**).
So the right question should be, *is there an html markup which shows up this keybaord on iOS*?

The project is Cordova based.

Comment: it is possible, you should learn javascript mutual with oc(or swift), you should use the `webView` to load the html, in it you should appoint the js method.

Comment: thanks @aircraft . I'm using Cordova and it already "laods" the html from native cose. Exactly what do you mean with "to appoint the js method"? Do you know a js which triggers that keyboard type? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

. and , are culture specific. If you set region as Germany from iphone settings you can see ',' on keypad of type UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad. If you want to show ',' in all region and languages you need to add it in accessory view of keypad. Not sure how it will be implemented in your case but in Xamarin we did this by adding native rendered for keyboard.

Comment: That's not the answer to the question

Answer (score -1):

If you want that, for all contexts, the point separator to be replaced by a comma separator, I suggest to modify the `CFBundleLocalizations` key in `Info*.plist` with fr_FR (or any other localization for who the float separator is a ',').

For Cordova that you seem to use, I suggest the use of a bespoke plugin, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46405401/2728710

Comment: That's not the answer to the question

Comment: I supposed that, given my proposition change the "Done" in the keyboard (in the screenshot you made) in "OK" in french, it will change the comma by a dot too.

I'm surprised that it's not the case because of the answer of Vishal.

Comment: The question is about showing that keyboard with an html input! not in native code

Comment: But what is the purpose? The keyboard of an iOS device is a native element, triggered by the html markup, indeed, but native in the end.

I really doubt that you can modify the organisation of the keys via HTML.

Comment: No, that's not the point. The point is: "triggered by the html markup". The question asks which html to use in order to trigger that keyboard!!

Comment: Understood. In ours projects, we only use <input type="tel"> as the least worse option for this use case.

Comment: Well, input tel will show the tel keyboard which has other characters. I asked this wondering if there's a method to show this keyboard because it exisists in iOS sdk